# How to exclude all JUnit4 tests with a given category using Maven surefire?

Tags: junit, maven-2, junit4, maven-surefire-plugin

I intend on annotating some of my JUnit4 tests with an @Category annotation. I would then like to exclude that category of tests from running on my Maven builds.

I see from the [Maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html#Using_JUnit_Categories) that it is possible to specify a category of tests **to** run. I want to know how to specify a category of tests **not** to run.

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

Your pom.xml should contain the following setup.

```
<configuration>
   <excludes>
       <exclude>**/TestCircle.java</exclude>
        <exclude>**/TestSquare.java</exclude>
   </excludes>
</configuration>
```

If you want regex support just use

```
<excludes>
    <exclude>%regex[.*[Cat|Dog].*Test.*]</exclude>
</excludes>
```

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

If you want to use Category annotation, you need to do the following:

```
@Category(com.myproject.annotations.Exclude)
@Test
public testFoo() {
   ....
}
```

In your maven configuration, you can have something like this

```
<configuration>
  <excludedGroups>com.myproject.annotations.Exclude</excludedGroups>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I cant find anything referencing `excludedGroups` for surefire

Comment: @Hafiz Read this.. https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/categories

Comment: i understand that `com.myproject.annotations.Exclude` is a class/interface (https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html) it should be used as:  @Category(com.myproject.annotations.Exclude.class) - see bottom of the https://baeldung-cn.com/junit-filtering-tests