# How to setup a JUnit run configuration by category in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I want to create a JUnit run configuration with all tests in my project, but I only want to include a certain JUnit category.

In Maven, I would have an argument like `-Dgroups=com.categories.my`.

Is there any kind of a program argument or how am I supposed to do this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring maven - run specific tests (via annotations or maven profile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47162013/spring-maven-run-specific-tests-via-annotations-or-maven-profile)

Comment: I want to do it with the eclipse JUnit run configuration and not with maven